# Is there any solution for the glitch i see when i open my website for first time?

Tags: html, css

I set up my website up and running but it shows a minor glitch when opened the first time. Here is the link : [www.voip-account.com](https://www.voip-account.com)

This is not any WordPress theme and its purely HTML and CSS. I don't know what code to add here and I can't understand the problem.
Need help to identify the problem.

Comment: Is the "glitch" you're talking about when you open it, it flashes or elements move position? This is because images or code hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: Exactly, the CSS / JS has not loaded yet so it shows up on top of each other. You should set `visibility: hidden` on these elements and show them only after their respective files are loaded.

Comment: I have used    `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">` Does this affects the problem i am having?

Answer (score 0):

You could add for each image a `.onload` function, to check if they onloaded, once they all loaded, then you can display them.

Comment: The glitch we are seeing are not images.They are just some text or styles